# SocketException - 'Socket is closed' even when isConnected() returns true

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm making and android app that uses socket communication to send an image to a java app running on a computer

Here's what's happening : The desktop is running a server java application, the client android application is run on the device, it transfers an image to the server and that part goes well. After that the server app takes in a line from the console and passes it back to the android app. TILL that message is received by the android app, it is supposed to show a progress dialog box and it gets stuck there. The android app is supposed to read the string passed by the desktop app using readLine() but when I try to open the inputstream over the socket in the android app it gives me the exception.

Following are the codes, first for the desktop server, then for the android client

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;

```
class ProjectServer
{
    ServerSocket serSock;
    Socket  sock;

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        try
        {
            ProjectServer cs=new ProjectServer();
            cs.startServer();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void startServer()
    {
        try
        {
            serSock=new ServerSocket(8070);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            sock=serSock.accept();


            System.out.println("Connections done");


            //Accept File
            System.out.println("Connected");
            System.out.println(sock.isConnected()+"1");

            //receive code

            int filesize=450660;
            int bytesRead;
            int current=0;
            // receive file
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Project Server\\Capture.png");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;


            do {
               bytesRead =
                  is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
               if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            System.out.println("end-start");
            bos.close();
            //sock.close();
            //receive code ends

            //System.out.println(br.readLine());


            //Matlab computation

            //Send result
            System.out.println(sock.isConnected()+"2");
            PrintWriter pr=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);

            pr.println((new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine());
            System.out.println(sock.isConnected()+"3");
            (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();
            System.out.println(sock.isConnected()+"4");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Android Client:

```
package com.site.custom;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Act2 extends Activity
{
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private String serverIP="58.146.100.187";
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private String path;
    private Socket cliSock;

    public void onCreate(Bundle onCreateInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(onCreateInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        this.setTitle("This has started");
        path=getIntent().getStringExtra("path");

        //Establish Connection
        //pd=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Establishing connection", "Finding server",false,true);

        try
        {
            cliSock=new Socket(serverIP,8070);

            //pd.dismiss();
            //Log.v("MERA MSG","changing text");
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tview)).setText(path);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("MERA MSG",e.toString());
        }

        //Send file
        //Log.v("MERA MSG","changing text1");

        ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Sending image", "Image chosen:"+path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("//")+1),false,true);
        //Log.v("MERA MSG","changing text2");

        try
        {


            File myFile = new File (path);
            System.out.println((int)myFile.length());
            byte[] mybytearray  = new byte[450560];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = cliSock.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            bis.close();
            //sock.close();
            //System.out.println("Completed");
            System.out.println(cliSock.isConnected()+"1");
            pd.dismiss();
            //System.out.println("Done");
            System.out.println(cliSock.isConnected()+"2");
            //Show dialog box till computation results arrive
            pd=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Recognizing...", "(waiting for server reply)",false,true);
            System.out.println(cliSock.isConnected()+"3");
            in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliSock.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
            pd.dismiss();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("MERA MSG",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

And btw here are the logs from LogCat:
http://pastebin.com/atHMycTa
You can confirm that the socket is still connected here as it shows true on lines 350 and 349
Look at line 351 for the error.

Comment: I'm not sure if this might be the cause, but can you try to move the `os.close()` call to after you read your data from the socket. I can't remember if closing the outputstream also closes the socket, or if it's only when closing the inputstream this happens..

Comment: @patrick No it doesn't, see my answer.

Comment: @EJP: Oh, sorry, must have gotten it confused with something else..

Comment: @Patrick "No it doesn't" refers to your statement "`isConnected` returns the connected state of the previous operation". Closing either stream of a `Socket` does close the socket and the other stream.

Comment: @EJP: Yeah, I noticed after I wrote the comment. That's why I removed the first one ;)

Answer (score 2):

isConnected() only tells you whether you have ever connected *this Socket,* which you have, so it returns true. It is not an indication of the state of the *connection.*

Comment: @GrowinMan Your problem is that you have closed your Socket and then continued to use it. Closing the output stream closes the socket. Just flush it, then get the input stream, then proceed. Also you don't need any of those `ByteArrayOutputStreams`. They are just wasting time and space. Read from the file, write to the socket, or *vice versa.*

Comment: The flush command() doesn't seem to work. If I just do flush() then the server still keeps waiting for the image to be received. Only after I do os.close() it really flushes the stream and the server receives the image completely and moves ahead with execution. Is there a way by which I can flush the output stream without closing it?

Comment: @GrowinMan The server is reading to EOS. So you need to send one. Call cliSock.shutdownOutput() after the flush.